# MobiLink: How to export database users to remote database created via Sybase Central

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sap, mobilink

How to configure a Sybase Central MobiLink project in the way, it's also exporting the database users of consolidated database to a remote database?

In default it appears to only create `dba` with default password which seems to come direct from `dbinit`.

A manual trick would be to add some custom SQL to the create .sql-file or execute later some custom code. But I'm wondering whether I can add some customer code, or even better the users direct, to the Sybase Central project so it's always included when I'm using deployment etc.